# getting Wrong output when fetching data from multiple table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

When i am trying to run this query its giving wrong output

```
SELECT
 (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD')) AS ORDER_DATE,
 (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD-mon-yyyy')),
 SUM(sale_order.amount_total)
FROM
 public.sale_order_line,
 public.product_product,
 public.product_template,
 public.product_category,
 public.sale_order
WHERE
 sale_order_line.product_id = product_product.id AND
 product_product.product_tmpl_id = product_template.id AND
 product_template.categ_id = product_category.id AND
 sale_order.id = sale_order_line.order_id AND
 product_category.name = 'Bboy'
 and
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'MON') =  'MAR' --${sale_month} AND
 and
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'YYYY') = '2015'  --'${sale_year}

GROUP BY
      (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD-mon-yyyy')),
       (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD'))
ORDER BY
 ORDER_DATE ASC
```

I think it multiply the row but not able to solve .
How i can solve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could go into a little more detail about what the wrong output is, and what the right output would look like.

Comment: The value of SUM is showing greater then real value

Comment: In that case, try a query that doesn't do the grouping, and returns the raw sales order information.  That way you can see what records it is going to SUM and you can decide why a record is in there that shouldn't be.

Not knowing much about your schema I can't help much more, but I'd suspect its because the sales_order.amount_total is the total value of a sales order, not just the value of 'Bboy' sales items on that order.  So if you had an order with a $50 Bboy item, and a $75,000 mercedes, the value you're using would be $75,050

Comment: Hint: `and
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'MON') =  'MAR' AND
 and
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'YYYY') = '2015'` should be replaced with `sale_order.date_order>='01-03-2015'::date and sale_order.date_order<'01-04-2015'::date`. Latter form will utilize possibly existing indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your code using subquery. I hope that will help you to get data without multiplying rows.

```
SELECT
 (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD')) AS ORDER_DATE,
 (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD-mon-yyyy')),
 SUM(sale_order.amount_total)
FROM
 public.sale_order 
WHERE
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'MON') =  'MAR' --${sale_month} AND
 and
 TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'YYYY') = '2015'  --'${sale_year}
 and exists 
    (select product_category.name 
    from 
        public.product_category 
    inner join 
        public.product_template
    on (product_template.categ_id = product_category.id)
    inner join 
        public.sale_order_line
    on (sale_order_line.product_id = product_product.id)
    where
         sale_order.id = sale_order_line.order_id and
        product_category.name = 'Bboy' 
    )

GROUP BY
      (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD-mon-yyyy')),
       (TO_CHAR(sale_order.date_order,'DD'))
ORDER BY
 ORDER_DATE ASC
```